# Ore's theorem, sequence of degrees

Tags: graph-theory

Can it be verified that if the conditions in the Ore's theorem are satisfied, then for any $1\leq k <n/2$ we have $d_k>k$?
(the sequence of degrees is non-decreasing, i.e., $d_1\leq d_2\leq ...\leq d_n$.)